# How can I get pdb's debugger working while running uvicorn using uvicorn.run()?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to debug a FastAPI application and came across [this blog post](https://jaketrent.com/post/debug-fastapi-pdb/) describing how to run uvicorn from the command line with a `--debug` flag to get `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to work.

But I'm running my FastAPI app with `uvicorn.run()` from within a `main.py` file, and it seems `uvicorn.run()` doesn't have a `debug` keyword argument.

So how can I get `pdb.set_trace()` to work?

Comment: My guess is that you have to set the logging level to `debug`. https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#logging

Comment: Also, there is no `--debug` option for running from the command line https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-from-the-command-line

Comment: `--log-level ='debug' ` Options: 'critical', 'error', 'warning', 'info', 'debug', 'trace'.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it turned out that PyCharm's debugger actually worked with FastAPI without needing to set any special options other than running the program in PyCharm's debug mode.